# Excel: Need helping using the IF function in an excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

My function looks like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("[a href=""url", LEFT(J2,SEARCH(";",J2)-1), ".asp""]link text[/a]", "[/br][/br]", B2)
```

The `LEFT/SEARCH` function is taking the cell value of `J2` up until the first semicolon. I'd like to incorporate an `IF` function in order to take the entire cell value of `J2` if there is no semi colon. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming you have Excel 2007+):

```
=CONCATENATE("[a href=""url", IFERROR(LEFT(J2,SEARCH(";",J2)-1),J2), ".asp""]link text[/a]", "[/br][/br]", B2)
```

If not, let me know and i'll give you a different formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=CONCATENATE("[a href=""url", LEFT(J2,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(";",J2),LEN(J2),SEARCH(";",J2)-1))), ".asp""]link text[/a]", "[/br][/br]", B2)
```